# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter') angular

Tags: angular

i want to do Cascading Dropdown List Using Angular 11
when i am trying to do this i got error related to filter
my api response is array of object thats why i face this problem
i want to display when i select policy type from first dropdown then display sub policy type of  in another dropdown list

i got this error
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')

and my api response is like below

```
"data": [
        {
            "policy_type": "Four Wheeler",
            "policy_sub_type": [
                "SAOD"
            ]
        },
        {
            "policy_type": "Two Wheeler",
            "policy_sub_type": [
                "Comprehensive",
                "SAOD"
            ]
        }
    ]
```

this is my api response

below is my service

```
getPolicyTypeList() {
    return this._http.get(this.baseUrl + 'policy_type_list', {})
  }
```

now below is my ts file code

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.PolicyTypeList();
    this.onSelect(this.selectedPolicyType.policy_type);
  }
  PolicyTypeList() {
    this._policyservice.getPolicyTypeList().subscribe(
      (resp: any) => {
        if (resp.success == 1) {
          this.policyTypeListing = resp.data;
        }
        console.log(resp.data)
      }
    )
  }
  onSelect(policytype: any) {
    console.log(policytype.target.value);
      this._policyservice.getPolicyTypeList().subscribe(
     (resp: any) => {
       this.subPolicyType = resp.policy_type.filter((e: any) => e.policytype == policytype.target.value);
       console.log(this.subPolicyType)
     } 
   )
  }
```

below is my html

````
<li class="list-inline-item pe-3">
          <div class="floating-form">
            <div class="floating-label">
              <select class="form-select floating-select" (change)="onSelect($event)"
                onclick="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);" value="" style="width: 200px;">
                <option></option>
                <option>all</option>
                <option *ngFor="let pt of policyTypeListing" [value]="pt.policy_type">{{pt.policy_type}}</option>
              </select>
              <span class="highlight"></span>
              <label>Policy Type Listing</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-inline-item pe-3">
          <div class="floating-form">
            <div class="floating-label">
              <select class="form-select floating-select" onclick="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);" value=""
                style="width: 200px;">
                <option></option>
                <option>all</option>
                <option *ngFor="let pt of subPolicyType | async" [value]="pt.policy_sub_type">{{pt.policy_sub_type}}
                </option>
              </select>
              <span class="highlight"></span>
              <label>Sub Policy Type Listing</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
```

please help me on it
````

Comment: It means that `resp.policy_type` is `undefined`. You can place a breakpoint in order to make sure that the problem comes from there. Then, it means that you have a problem with the API, not the code (or you should handle the case when this field is undefined)

Comment: sorry i can't understand your point but can you explain me in brief or with code please help me i am doing this from last 2 days i will very thankful to you

Answer (score 1):

As requested, here is a better explaination (did not have place in comments)

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')

This means that you are trying to access the attribute `filter` of an object that is actually `undefined`, as if you tried to access `undefined.filter`

The only place in the code where you try to access an attribute called `filter` is here :

```js
  onSelect(policytype: any) {
    console.log(policytype.target.value);
      this._policyservice.getPolicyTypeList().subscribe(
     (resp: any) => {
       this.subPolicyType = resp.policy_type.filter((e: any) => e.policytype == policytype.target.value); 
                                          // ^^^^^^ 
       console.log(this.subPolicyType)
     } 
   )
  }
```

it means that the `Observable` `this._policyservice.getPolicyTypeList()` gives you a value `resp` that does not contain the field `policy_type`, resulting in  `resp.policy_type` to be `undefined`

You can try to add a breakpoint if you want to be sure that the problem comes from there. If you do not know how to add a breakpoint (depends on your tooling), you can just add a `console.log` :

```js
this._policyservice.getPolicyTypeList().subscribe(
     (resp: any) => {
       console.log('resp is ', resp); // <<< HERE
       this.subPolicyType = resp.policy_type.filter((e: any) => e.policytype == policytype.target.value);
```

Also, you can check directly the value that is returned by the backend by inspecting the request via the Chrome console

Now, if `resp` does not contain the field `policy_type`, you should ask if this is a normal use case.

- Maybe the backend is broken and should always send this field (so, ask the backend developers to fix the API)
- Or maybe it is normal for the backend to not send the field, then it means that you have to adapt the code.

It is also possible that you should not access `resp.policy_type` but something else like `resp.body.policy_type`

Comment: thanks i do this as you tell me  its showing proper response in console and i also do resp.body.policy_type this but it showing  this error  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'policy_type') what can i do

Comment: @sonalighadge What is displayed in the console for the `resp` value ?

Comment: {message: 'Policy type list found', success: '1', data: Array(2)}
data: Array(2)
0:
policy_sub_type: ['SAOD']
policy_type: "Four Wheeler"
[[Prototype]]: Object
1:
policy_sub_type: (2) ['Comprehensive', 'SAOD']
policy_type: "Two Wheeler"
[[Prototype]]: Object
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
message: "Policy type list found"
success: "1"

Comment: @sonalighadge ok, so the structure of the response is not what you expected. Here, `resp.policy_type` does not exist. But you have `resp.data` which contains an array of 2 objects that have a `policy_type` field. Looking at the code, it seems that you want to find the object that has the right `policy_type` and extract its `policy_sub_type`. So I think that what you need is `this.subPolicyType = resp.data.filter((e: any) => e.policytype == policytype.target.value)[0].policy_sub_type;` or something like that

Comment: @sonalighadge Also, if you just want to find the first that matches the condition, you can use `find` instead of `filter` : `this.subPolicyType = resp.data.find((e: any) => e.policytype == policytype.target.value).policy_sub_type`

Comment: now i got this error    core.mjs:6484 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'policy_sub_type')

Comment: @sonalighadge it means that `find/filter` did not return any result. Can you `console.log('searched policy_type : ' + policytype.target.value)`

Comment: When I am trying to do policytype.target.value I go error on value so that's why I removed value then I got above error